# Image aspect ratio while zooming, one div taking over another

Tags: html, css, css-position

I started to learn CSS a few days ago and I have a problem, which I really don't know how to solve.

I want all images to stay the same (with the original aspect ratio while zooming the page). But when I'm zooming the page images are taking over my other image (background) at the top. And my footer is missing as well...

I want first two and the last two (on a new line) images at the bottom of the page with the same width (50% of the page) and height no more than 500px, but with normal aspect ratio.

Here's nice working example of exactly what I want, but there're hell of a lot of those styles and I even don't know from what to start with. https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/61406.html

Maybe it would've been better to use some other tag, not the tag. And make those images like backgrounds? But I've tried a lot of variations and nothing changed :(

Here's my code https://jsfiddle.net/ayhj9vb0/364/

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

/* Properties for background image here */
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://citywallpaperhd.com/download/71-huge-impressive-city-at-night.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


#logo {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}


#navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#navigation ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li {
    width: 15%;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#navigation a {
    padding: 5px; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#navigation a.current {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 8px; 
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: #ff9900;
}


#banner-text {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 250px 50px; 
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#banner-text p {
    width: 800px; 
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
}


#main-content img, #main-content-2 img{
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 500px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}


#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav id="navigation">

            <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"/>

            <ul>
                <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="banner-text">
            <h1>h1 text</h1>
            <p>
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main-content">
        <img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-32.jpg"/><img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-32.jpg"/>
   </div>
   
   <div id="main-content-2">
     <img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-34.jpg"/><img src="https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_61406/images/post-34.jpg"/>
   </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

    </body>
```

Please help! :(

P. S. Pardon my English

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following css:

```
#main-content img, #main-content-2 img{
  max-height: 500px; /* remove this line */
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/egdeLy1c/

Comment: That worked, thanks. But those images go up when I'm zooming. How to prevent this?

Comment: Great! Please ask a new question if this one is solved.